# QML nextItemInFocusChain() not working, always refers to self

Tags: qt, qml

Calling nextItemInFocusChain() from a child QML component seems to always return the current component. Understandably, calling forceActiveFocus() on that next item does nothing. Note that navigation via the tab key still works as expected.

Minimally Reproducible Example:

**qml.qrc**

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/qml">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>Child.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif
 
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
 
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
 
 
    engine.load(url);
    return app.exec();
} // main
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
 
 
ApplicationWindow {
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true
    visibility: "FullScreen"
    title: "HelloWorld"
 
    RowLayout {
        spacing: 30
        width: 600
 
        Child {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            id: test1
        }
 
        Child {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            id: test2
        }
 
        Child {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            id: tes3
        }
    }
 
    onActiveFocusItemChanged: print("activeFocusItem: ", activeFocusItem)
}
```

**child.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
 
 
Item {
 
    function focusNext()
    {
        console.log("focusing next...")
        nextItemInFocusChain().forceActiveFocus()
    }
 
    Keys.onReturnPressed: focusNext()
 
    TextField {
        text: "TEST"
    }
 
}
```

Comment: @eyllanesc I've revised my question and included the MRE

Answer (score 1):

Putting the logic directly in the TextField results in the correct behavior:

```
TextField {
...
    Keys.onReturnPressed: nextItemInFocusChain().forceActiveFocus()
}
```

It's unclear to me why the parent item cannot redirect focus in this way.